# Personalizar os templates de URI usando o OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restful

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que contém o pacote [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/), que oferece uma implementação bem simplificada para suporte ao OData V3, bastando apenas usar o Atributo `EnableQueryAttribute` nos métodos ou classes onde queremos habilitar o suporte:

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Filter |
                                   AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy |
                                   AllowedQueryOptions.Select)]
public IQueryable<Vaga> GetVagas()
{
    return db.Vagas;
}
```

No entanto, a versão mais recente do pacote - que dá suporte ao OData V4 - não oferece uma implementação tão simplificada pois trata a resolução da URI e cobre convenções de rotas, como pode ser visto em [**um dos exemplos**](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-04-custom-routing-convention) da [documentação oficial](http://odata.github.io/WebApi).

Na documentação encontrei meios de personalizar as resoluções de controllers e actions, mas o formato das URI que o pacote espera não segue o padrão REST e eu gostaria de personalizá-lo também, como é possivel nas rotas de WebApi padrão.

### WebApi padrão

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: $"MyRoute",
    routeTemplate: $"api/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

### Com OData

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

builder.EntitySet<Produto>("Produtos").EntityType.HasMany(p => p.Fornecedores);
builder.EntitySet<Fornecedor>("Fornecedores").EntityType.HasKey(l => l.IdFornecedor);

config.MapODataServiceRoute($"MyODataRoutes", $"api/odata/", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

```
 _________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|                       |      *Formato suportado pelo pacote*      |         *Formato esperado*          |
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|                       | site.com/Produtos(2)/Fornecedor(5)        | site.com/Produtos/2/Fornecedor/5    |
|*Template equivalente* | ~/entityset/key/navigation/key            | ~/entityset/key/navigation/key      |
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Alguém sabe como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Asp.Net Core você tem que configurar assim:

```cs
            app.UseMvc(b =>
            {
                var odataOptions = new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataOptions() { UrlKeyDelimiter = ODataUrlKeyDelimiter.Slash };
                b.SetDefaultODataOptions(odataOptions);
                b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
            });
```

Comment: Apesar de eu não estar usando o asp.net-core ainda, acredito que isso responde a pergunta. Obrigado